# Sending a command to a server from Raspberry Pi (Python)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

So I'm using this Escape Room software, which in all truth seems pretty shoddily put together (http://www.escaperoombuilder.com/en/cms/download/) but I have to use it nonetheless. We are trying to implement a Raspberry Pi as a microcontroller so that when the server receives a signal/prompt from the Pi it will display "Hello World", just as a proof of concept. According to the software manual:

"Incoming messages from external devices
If you send message from her anotdevice (TCP, UDP, Serial) using the proper syntax, the server runs a script of your choosing.
Syntax example: @scriptname.ers
The @ character indicates that a script should be run, followed by the actual name of the script. This allows for external applications or devices to kick off scripts within the Escaperoom Software server."

I've managed to successfully connect my Pi to the correct socket port for the room I'm running, but that's pretty much as far as I've gotten. Could someone guide me as to what my next step would be?

This is the code I have so far:

```
import socket
host = '192.168.1.158'
port = 13803

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host, port))

s.send(("@Action.HelloWorld.ers").encode())

s.close()
```

Sorry if this is a simple misunderstanding, the software manual/website contains no examples of how to properly implement this and I am a tad rusty at Python.

Comment: I'm guessing you want `port=13803` rather than `socket=13803`

Comment: @MarkSetchell whooooops my bad yeah i meant port. It was correct in my script I just copied it over wrong. Any idea what else could be an issue?